# Adding a View to ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a class that extends `View`. I want to add it to a `ScrollView` programmatically. I'm able to add it to a `LinearLayout` but have no success with a `ScrollView`. What gives?

```
sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sv);

myview = new MyViewClass(this);
myview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

sv.addView(myview);
```

Comment: Are you calling setContentView(sv); ?

Comment: no, I'm calling setContentView(R.layout.main) which contains the scrollview

Answer (score 1):

You can add your View to the ScrollView `if its the only view in the ScrollView`.

Otherwise you will get `ScrollView can have only 1 direct child` exception.

To add multiple Views to a ScrollView. First add a Linear or Relative Layout in the ScrollView and then add Views to this Layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonUserInfo = actionObject.getUserInfoID(urlsId).getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i);
ModeUser userinf=new ModeUser();
userinf.Male=jsonUserInfo.getString("sex");
userinf.userName=jsonUserInfo.getString("first_name");
userinf.UserLastName=jsonUserInfo.getString("last_name");
UserInfoDatInList.add(userinf);
```